# Natural Language Processing Solution in Java?

Tags: java, nlp

Are there any equally great packages like Python's NTLK in Java world ?

Comment: See [Java : Is there a good natural language processing library ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870460/java-is-there-a-good-natural-language-processing-library)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two popular ones that I know of are:

[Gate](http://gate.ac.uk/)

[OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Also [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/) is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

[Stanford](http://nlp.stanford.edu/) has a very good collection of NLP tools.

Answer (score 1):

For other JVM languages see

- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/): [Scala NLP](http://www.scalanlp.org/)
- Clojure: [clojure-opennlp](http://github.com/dakrone/clojure-opennlp)

Answer (score 0):

[ClearTK](http://code.google.com/p/cleartk/) provides a Java framework for doing statistical NLP.  Its strength is not so much in its libraries, but in providing the infrastructure and wrappers for rich feature extraction and model training.