# NLP Library for Java Programming Language

Tags: java, nlp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : Is there a good natural language processing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870460/java-is-there-a-good-natural-language-processing-library)

are there any known open source distributions that one can use like nltk for python?

Comment: Do we really not have enough people frequenting the `nlp` tag who can vote to close questions?

Answer (score 0):

[GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) is the most famous industry-level librarywith a java implementation I can think of.

It is truly powerful.

Otherwise:

- [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/)
- [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/)

Xerox used to have a set of nice online tools as well, but I don't know if they have a Java implementation or any accessible web-services for them.