# Natural Language Processing in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, nlp

I'm a newbie to windows 8 programming, C# and NLP.

I'm looking for a library that allows me to use NLP in windows 8.

I found SharpNLP but it is very poorly documented with no tutorials. I've also come across the Antelope framework but this seems to have even worse documentation.

Is there any resource that'll help me (either tutorials or a better documented framework)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what sort of NLP tools you need? NLP can be a blanket term for a lot of different algorithms/techniques.

Comment: In simple terms I'm looking for a tool to parse sentences to extract "information" and send that to a database. Basically try to create a DB of meaningful information from sentences.

Comment: That was probably the vaguest sentence I ever wrote but I'm a newbie to NLP and my professor told me to work in it for windows phone or windows 8 metro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharpNLP looks fine. It's the port of the [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/), so you can probably just read the OpenNLP's documentation.
There is also [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) (a .Net version of [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/))
It's a search engine and (I guess) should have some NLP inside. I'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: Yep looks like I'm stuck translating the documentation. Nice job though. This gives the overview of every tool brilliantly so its definitely worth a read through

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, these libraries are available for `C#` and might be useful. However, I'm not sure if they work in Metro apps.

- [Proxem](https://www.proxem.com/en/technology/antelope-framework/)
- [AlchemyAPI](http://www.alchemyapi.com/tools/)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much in C#. I recommend Java. There are a ton of Java libraries that do NLP and they all work fine in Windows. Plus, Java isn't that much different from C#, and your code will also run on *nix if you need it to. See:

http://opennlp.apache.org/

[Which NLP toolkit to use in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895893/which-nlp-toolkit-to-use-in-java)

[NLP Library for Java Programming Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277887/nlp-library-for-java-programming-language)

Comment: No. I know there isn't much in C#. But I'm looking into offline processing in a windows 8 app. In which case I don't see a way to use Java.