# NLP Library in java

Tags: java, search, nlp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : Is there a good natural language processing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870460/java-is-there-a-good-natural-language-processing-library)

I need a simple Natural Language Processing library written in java which can be used to process a search query/question. What I want actually is to **separate the main subject which is being searched in a query**. For an example, considering a query like "What is an apple?", it's perfect if the main search word apple can be extracted. This is for a semantic search engine development purpose.

Can anyone please suggest a suitable nlp library for this??

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for you that I see is to use **concept tagging** from [AlchemyAPI](https://web.archive.org/web/20161126133930/http://www.alchemyapi.com:80/api). You can also use some plugins for libraries from questions, pointed in comments, especially pay attention to **[OpenNLP](https://web.archive.org/web/20120306022203/http://incubator.apache.org:80/opennlp/)** and **[GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/)**. If you are going to build **ontology-based search engine**, I recommend you reading [this](http://www.springerlink.com/content/462t8871w5255l13/) paper on ontology-based interpretation of keywords, that shows some tendencies in user's habits ([video version](https://web.archive.org/web/20201203081713/http://videolectures.net/iswc07_tran_obi/)). Otherwise, you'll better use some **statistical techniques** like [LSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis).

Answer (score -1):

Jakarta Lucene/Solr?
http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html