# Natural Language Processing in Java (NLP)

Tags: java, nlp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : Is there a good natural language processing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870460/java-is-there-a-good-natural-language-processing-library)

Can anybody tell me about a library for NLP in java? It would really be nice if is properly documented too. I have tried to work with lingpipe but I am not able to understand it completely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try the [Stanford - NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/index.shtml). It has many utilities and libraries for NLP like the Parts-Of-Speech Tagger,all of which are great to use and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanx Kazekage. Have you tried to make a parser with the help of this library? My projects main aim is to process the reviews of the products given by the users on the websites like IMDB, mobile phone reviews etc. So that I can grade them, rate them out of 5 as we generally see on the websites

Comment: I have used their POS-tagger. It is very accurate and pretty simple to use indeed. I worked on a similar application where I had to rate sentences depending on the kind of words in them, and finally only choose those sentences which have a high score.

Comment: Wow! Cool. This is the actual thing that I need to do. :) Thanx a lot for advice. I will get back to this forum if I face any problem.
By the way would it be possible for you to give me some sample code so that I can feel a bit easy?

Comment: Kindly accept any of the two answers as the correct answer by clicking on the tick mark below the voting arrows just on left side of the answer. :-)

Answer (score 5):

It is probably a bit late now, and I suppose you must have moved on with your project. But you can anyways check [this](http://rajvardhan.wordpress.com/) blog out. It has a series of posts on nlp with java. [Stanford-NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/), as suggested by others is a great library to work with.

Most of the libraries will help you in the lexical analysis phase (sentence segmentation, tokenization, POS tagging, parsing, etc.) so that you don't have to start your code from scratch. All the best !

Answer (score 3):

These are 2 other libraries for NLP which you can use.

- [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/)
- [Stanford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/)

Stanford NLP Group has an effective combination of sophisticated and deep linguistic modeling and data analysis with innovative probabilistic and machine learning approaches to NLP.

Comment: ok. Thanx a lot Andrew. Can you also tell me any link you know for understanding how to work on Stanford NLP?

Answer (score 2):

I've done some experimenting with [Apache OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/) with jRuby. Its quite nice and solid but at the time I write this poorly documented. If you try OpenNLP I suggest you read following articles:

- [Getting started with OpenNLP (Natural Language Processing)](http://danielmclaren.com/2007/05/11/getting-started-with-opennlp-natural-language-processing/)
- [Mining Wikipedia with Hadoop and Pig for Natural Language Processing](http://dev.blogs.nuxeo.com/2011/01/mining-wikipedia-with-hadoop-and-pig-for-natural-language-processing.html)
- [OpenNLP Tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/05/opennlp-tutorial/)
- [An UIMA Sentence Annotator using OpenNLP](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/04/uima-sentence-annotator-using-opennlp.html)

[Documentation for OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation.html) can be found [here](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation.html).

This is code from my project where I do **named entity recognition** with OpenNLP. Its written in jRuby. OpenNLP models are stored in database because the code runs on Heroku and you can't write on file system there.

- [Politiki Named Entity Recognition API for w/ OpenNLP, jRuby and Grape](https://github.com/otobrglez/politiki-ner/blob/master/api.rb)

Comment: Apache OpenNLP is good & improving with community. Here is a good basic tutorial http://itsallbinary.com/tutorial-natural-language-processing-in-java-using-apache-opennlp/. This has basic custom model training, analyzing inputs & enhancing model by retraining.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a quiet good [NLP tool list](http://www.ling.uni-potsdam.de/~kolb/nlp-tools.html). It's in german, but should work with google translate. But i list some nevertheless:

- [Mate tools (GPL V2)](http://code.google.com/p/mate-tools/)
- [OpenNLP (Apache License V2)](http://opennlp.apache.org/)
- [Stanford NLP (dual licensed, GPL V2)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/)
- [TreeTagger](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/corplex/TreeTagger/)

If you want the best for english, take Stanford, but its GPL v2. For not such popular languages, Treetagger is better (it just needs a smaller trainingcorpus to work). For example you get better results with TreeTagger on german texts, dont know the survey anymore, but if you want it, i can search for it. OpenNLP is not as good as the other tools, but its under the Apache License v2, which you should consider aswell.

Comment: But treetagger installation is a pain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503388/treetagger-installation-successful-but-cannot-open-par-file