# Which Java framework would you recommend for NLP and decision making?

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good natural language processing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870460/is-there-a-good-natural-language-processing-library)

I'm starting a hobby project where the goal is to create a to-do application that would use some form of AI to give suggestions and help plan time.

Since I'm a complete beginner in the AI field, I was hoping if you could point me to some resource or Java library (the application will be a Java web application) to get me started.

Some of the possible scenarios would be

- Finding tasks with some common nature and make suggestions to group them
- Trying to classify which "kinds" of items are done first
- Identify people or tasks even when not explicitly mentioned

I'm aware I need to catch up on some literature on the field, but at moment I'm lost at what may be the best topic to search for this information (decision making? NLP? ML?)

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this framework: The Stanford Natural Language Processing Group's Stanford CoreNLP. More info [Here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml). It comes under GNU licensing, you can find more information on that link