# Using LingPipe in android for NLP

Tags: android, nlp, sentiment-analysis, lingpipe

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/872464/3963427) answer, [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/index.html) is a good library to use in Java. I want to know if it can be used for android too. If possible, a link to sample code will be helpful. Mainly I am looking for offline sentiment analysis.

If there are better alternatives, please suggest. 
Thank you!

Comment: Did you figure out how to use lingpipe in android?